# Converting VSTO to Web Add-In

Tags: ms-word, office-js, office-js-helpers

Is there any way I could insert another document?
In VSTO-there is an option to insert document with InsertFile.Looking for something similar here.

Comment: Are you asking about MS Word?

Comment: Yes.There was option to insert an other word document in VSTO.I see insert paragraph and images in Web Addin.Was wondering if I could find the insert file option.

Answer (score 0):

The Office JS APIs do not provide an option for inserting a file.

What would be possible is to get the Word Open XML of a file, convert it to the OPC flat file format, then insert that using one of the `ooxml` methods available.